# How to retrieve Text Size and similar settings with CF?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Windows Mobile 6.0 devices have a Text Size setting that can be reached by clicking

Start -> Settings -> System -> Screen -> Text Size

How do I retrieve the value of that setting (Smallest ... Largest) from a program running on the .NET compact framework?

Comment: THis was asked before (maybe here, maybe newsgroup - I don't recall which) and I did some digging.  I determined that it is *not* in the registry.  That might help you save some time anyway (even if it isn't an answer).

Comment: @ctacke: Thanks, that's good to know! BTW, did you compare the registry before changing the setting to the registry after the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [SHGetUIMetrics API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416462.aspx).